# Consume API Rest from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, rest

the purpose of this question it´s because i do not know why i can not get this done.

First i have my api in nodejs + mongodb, and using POSTMAN i can see my api on http://localhost:3000/api/.

Now in AngularJS i have my routes, i have my service calling my api but when i run it i have this error:

angular.js:11756 GET http://localhost:8080/api/platillos 404 (Not Found), i thinks it´s due to my api is on port 3000 and my web is running on port 8080, but im not sure this is the problem, this is my code:

service.js

```
use strict';
angular.module("nightshift")
.constant("baseURL", "/api/")
.service("menuService", ["$http", "baseURL", function($http, baseURL) {
    this.getPlatillos = function() {
        return $http.get(baseURL + "platillos");
    }

    this.getPlatillo = function(index) {
        return $http.get(baseURL + "platillos/" + index);
    }
}])
```

controllers.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module("nightshift")
.controller("MenuController", ["$scope", "menuService", function($scope, menuService) {
    $scope.dishes = {};
    menuService.getPlatillos()
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("nice");
        console.log(response.data);
            $scope.dishes = response.data;
          },
          function(response) {
              console.log("hola" + response.statusText);
          })
}]);
```

my view Platillos.html

```
<div class = "container">
        <div class = "row row-content" ng-controller = "MenuController">
            <div class = "col-xs-12  col-sm-10">
                <ul class = "media-list">
                    <li class = "media" ng-repeat = "dish in dishes">
                        <div class = "media-left media-middle">
                            <a href = "#">
                                <img ng-src = {{dish.image}} class = "media-object img-thumbnail">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "media-body">
                            <h2 class = "media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                <span class = "badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                            </h4>
                            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

hope someone can help me

Comment: Define `baseURL` as absolute URL in development environment..

Comment: i have done that, but it is the same

Comment: In `.constant("baseURL", "/api/")`

Comment: 'GET http://localhost:8080/app/localhost:3000/api/platillos 404 (Not Found)', i changed to absolute url, and i get that error

Comment: Absolute URL in invalid.. Set it as `localhost:3000/api/`

Comment: it worked but now i get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/api/platillos. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:3000/api/platillos`

Comment: :(   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/platillos. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header over your API...Or server both client and server on the same port...

Comment: thanks a lot @Rayon it worked putting it in the server :)